# wordpress brander theme editing display of woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

http://ohri.srihari.guru

please click on the shopping cart link to see the page im referring to

i've been making this website for a while now, and I have been struggling in figuring out which files are responsible for what content is being displayed where. it is quite annoying at times, especially in this case with the shopping cart page. I don't need all the sidebar stuff displayed as it is displayed in the cart, with the "popular posts", "latest tweets" etc, and i don't know how.

I'm using AVATHEMES brander theme. and I am using wordpress of course, with woocommerce. I've tried editing the woocommerce cart template page. page-templates/woo-cart.php, to no avail. I modified the brander sidebar to remove most of the unneccesary things from the sidebar but i jsut cannot figure out how to get rid of this twitter feed with the text: "LATEST TWEET
@ AVATHEMES
No tweets available"

I even put my twitter handle there but its not replacing the @AVATHEMES. I have no idea how to figure out which .php file it is. Any help would be appreciated... I would like to remove this twitter feed or possibly the whole sidebar, and if there was just a way to isolate which PHP file is generating the content it would help me so much going forward in customizing php templates made for WP websites...